# Missing operator error using batch file

Tags: batch-file, operators, command-prompt

I've been trying to create a little batchscript to get the usages of your browser. So far so good everything works, it does what it should. Then I moved the file to another pc and now I'm getting "Missing Operator" errors eventho the program runs like it should. Any idea's?

```
@echo off
set date = %date
set time = %time
set sum=0
for /f "tokens=5 delims=," %%x in ('tasklist /fo csv /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=.K " %%a in ("%%~x") do set /a sum+=%%a%%b%%c%%d
)
echo %date%, %time%, firefox.exe, %sum%K > FirefoxDumpResult.csv
pause

:start
set date = %date
set time = %time
set sum=0
for /f "tokens=5 delims=," %%x in ('tasklist /fo csv /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe"') do (
  for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=.K " %%a in ("%%~x") do set /a sum+=%%a%%b%%c%%d
)
echo %date%, %time%, firefox.exe, %sum%K >> FirefoxDumpResult.csv
set choice=
set /p choice="Do you want to log another one? Press 'y' and enter for Yes: "
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='y' goto start
```

Comment: `set date = %date` and `set time = %time` are wrong (but they do actually not cause the error as they are useless due to point 2.): 1. the spaces around the `=` sign become part of the variable names and values, unintentionally; 2. the closing `%` signs are missing; 3. **never** attempt to write to built-in variables! To get help, you should describe precisely what your script is expected to do and what it actually does... hint: `set /A` is throwing the error message...

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to tell me in 3. It's one of the first times I'm making a bat. As far as I understand sum already exists as variable so you ask me not to, but even when I use another var then sum it throws the same thing.

When looking into documentation I get stuff like this:
+=  || Add variable   ||    set /a "_num+=5"
So I don't really see what I'm doing wrong except for the missing ' " ' I guess? But even that doesn't solve it.

Comment: You are trying to set `date` and `time`, which are bith built-in variables; that is what I was talking about.

Comment: Oh I was looking for a way to echo them actually and just couldn't find another way to make it work... Sorry for being so unhandy but I get what you mean. My problem on the Set /a stays tho, but could this be due to trying this script on a virtual server?
If I try this on a desktop it shows no errors but on my virtual windows on Mac (yes mac....) I get that error popping up.

Comment: Again: please describe precisely what your script is expected to do and what it actually does; "it does not work" or something like that is not enough! My guess is that some `tokens`/`delims` definitions are improper...

Comment: Well it takes the memory value and needs to sum it up if there are multiple processes running of it, for exemple chrome.exe there will be around 6 minimum. But those things work, the program behaves like it should, the functions work like they should and the resulting query is perfect. It just throws out that little error without knowing why it happens. It doesn't block anything or it doesn't break anything. It just is...

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39371998/edit) your question and put this explanation there! Anyway, the problem could have somethin to do with the number format of the Mem Usage value; it uses a 1000-separator from the system's locale settings, so `3200 K` might look like `3,000 K`, `3.000 K`, `3'000 K`, depending on these settings; the `set /A` command does not understand that; hence the solution might be to change `delims=.K ` to `delims=.,'K `; additionally, add `/NH` to `tasklist`... Consider that your whole approach fails in case an Image Name or Session Name comtains `,`...

Comment: Without echo off one of the outputs looks like this: MemoryLogging>Set/A "_sum+=414 032K" so there's no "," as far as I understand?

Comment: As I said, depending on localer settings; ensure the *last* character in the `delims` option is a _space_! I guess the space in `414 032K` causes the issue; I don't get why there is a `K` though, since it is one of the `delims`...

Comment: I don't either... sorry I'm really new to all this, thank you for your patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not placed the closing percent characters on your %DATE% and %TIME% variables.
Additionally you shouldn't be creating variables which already exist and which don't need setting anyhow.
You have also pointlessly repeated a section of your code.
Finally you have not used the simpler code I provided for you in an earlier reply to another similar question using chrome.exe.

Try this:

```
@Echo Off
If /I Not "%CD%\" Equ "%~dp0" CD /D %~dp0
>FirefoxDumpResult.csv Type Nul
:Start
Set "_sum=0"
For /F "Tokens=6-7 Delims=., " %%a In (
    'TaskList /NH /FI "ImageName Eq firefox.exe"') Do Set/A _sum+=%%a%%b
Echo=%DATE%, %TIME%, firefox.exe, %_sum%K>>FirefoxDumpResult.csv
Echo=
Echo=Firefox process information logged
Echo=
Choice /M "Do you want to log another one?" 
If ErrorLevel 2 Exit/B
GoTo :Start
```

These are the outputs from both your and my versions:

```
::-------------------------------- Akorna Output -------------------------------
Type Nul 1>FirefoxDumpResult.csv
Set _sum=0
For /F "Tokens=6-7 Delims=., " %a In ('TaskList /NH /FI "ImageName Eq firefox.exe"') Do Set/A "_sum+=%a%b"
Set/A "_sum+=414 032K" Missing operator.
Echo=wo 07/09/2016, 16:39:43,48, firefox.exe, 414K 1>>FirefoxDumpResult.csv
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------
::-------------------------------- Compo Output --------------------------------
Type Nul 1>FirefoxDumpResult.csv
Set "_sum=0"
For /F "Tokens=6-7 Delims=., " %a In ('TaskList /NH /FI "ImageName Eq firefox.exe"') Do Set/A _sum+=%a%b
Set/A _sum+=333232
Echo=09/09/2016, 10:23:22.56, firefox.exe, 333232K 1>>FirefoxDumpResult.csv
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You have clearly altered the script; please make sure, at least, that line five in the script you're using matches the one I posted.

Comment: This still gives off the same "Missing opperator" error tho. And I tried yours as well, this one was just the last one active in my txt batch for testing things out. All three versions return missing opperator for some reason.

Comment: Might it be that it gives missing opperator because I'm working on a virtual pc? On desktop pc's it's all code versions work without giving the "missing opperator" error.

Comment: My solution should be tested independent of your alterations. Without you providing the entire script you are running, how do you expect me to determine if the error is coming from my provided solution. Please post your entire script.

Comment: That actually is my entire script

Comment: Change **@Echo** to **On** on line one and copy/post the console output.

Comment: C:\Users\mbu\Desktop\MemoryLogging>Type Nul 1>FirefoxDumpResult.csv
C:\Users\mbu\Desktop\MemoryLogging>Set _sum=0
C:\Users\mbu\Desktop\MemoryLogging>For /F "Tokens=6-7 Delims=., " %a In ('TaskList /NH /FI "ImageName Eq firefox.exe"') Do Set/A "_sum+=%a%b"
C:\Users\mbu\Desktop\MemoryLogging>Set/A "_sum+=414 032K"
Missing operator.
C:\Users\mbu\Desktop\MemoryLogging>Echo=wo 07/09/2016, 16:39:43,48, firefox.exe, 414K 1>>FirefoxDumpResult.csv

Comment: Your output clearly shows a space in the resultant **%_sum%**. This cannot happen as the line above it **delimits spaces** and they will therefore not appear in the output of **%a%b**. If you haven't really removed the delimiter and fudged the output you've posted then please run the following command and post the output here: `TaskList /NH /FI "ImageName Eq firefox.exe"`

Comment: I have had access to a machine running firefox.exe and noticed differences in your output from mine. You have made changes, see my answer edit for details.

Comment: Eh sorry I was experimenting other solutions found on the web and have forgotten to revert them when I send in the resulting logs, in any case as odd as it might seem it was really a problem from running it from a Virtual pc for some odd reason. Higher-up decided to only use the script on desktops now and not virtuals so... guess this issue became irrelevant even tho I can't imagine why a script logs errors on a virtual machine and doesn't on a physical one. Thanks for all the help tho, really appreciate it.